# Spring Cloud stream & security

Tags: security, spring-cloud-stream

we are planning to use Spring cloud-stream with a Kafka binder as the eventing base for our application. But we are currently unable to make it work with Spring-security, which we use for HTTP request security. One example I see is with Spring-web-flux and with reactive method security.
Currently we don't use reactive/web flux.

Is this the only way for the same, or is there another way with spring-web and spring-security.
Any help in this regard is highly appreciated as I'm unable to find any info for the same.

Comment: Spring Cloud Stream applications are boot applications. Therefore any security that can be applied against a normal Spring Boot application can be applied on a stream application as well. If you are having issues with specific use cases, please elaborate and we can discuss that further here.

Comment: Thanks. Thanks Soby Chacko. I am currently doing a POC on Cloud-stream and we have a "SecurityConfig" that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.The configure method for the same has a HTTPSecurity to authorize all requests (http.authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll())). I have registered a filter too. HTTP/REST calls go through the filter. While messages sent to and consumed from a Kafka topic through cloud stream don't. Please do let me know if I'm doing something wrong. Also I was reading about GlobalMethodSecurity, Should I be using this instead?

Comment: Here is a blog that has some details about security with Spring Cloud Stream. I see that this is using a stream function with security built into it. You might want to take a look to see if it is applicable in your case: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-cloud-stream-a-brief-guide

Comment: I saw this post and this was for a spring web-flux project and reactive security. I was looking for something for a regular spring-web application.

Comment: Hi Soby. I went through the example code, and from what I understand only the actual endpoint/controller handler method is secured through JWT. While the actual publishing and subscribing(consuming) bypass the auth mechanism. is that how it works? Or did I get it wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.